# What is the probability distribution of the total passengers on two successive trips?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On each trip, the number of passengers on a subway line path, denoted by N, has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ (that is, $P(N=k) = {e^{- \lambda} \lambda \over k!}$ , for $k=0,1, \ldots$).

What is the probability distribution of the total passengers on two successive trips?

Let X = total number of passengers in the first trip

Let Y = total number of passengers in the second trip

Both X and Y have Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. So the questions is basically what is the distribution of the sum of two Poisson distribution with the same mean. Right?

$P(X+Y = n)$

Let ${X+Y=n} = {X=k, Y=n-k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$

Then, $P(X+Y = n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}P(X=k, Y=n-k)$

Since X and Y are independent

$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n} P(X=k, Y=n-k) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=n-k)
\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k}\over k ! } \times {e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{n-k}\over (n-k) !}
\\
&=  e^{-2 \lambda} \lambda^{n} \times \sum_{k=0}^{n} {1 \over  k ! (n-k) !}
\\
 & = {e^{-2 \lambda} \lambda^{n} \over n! }\times \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n! \over  k ! (n-k) !} \\
&= {e^{-2 \lambda} \lambda^{n} \over n! }\times 2^{n} 
\end{align}$

The first term would be a Poisson distribution with mean $2 \lambda$. I don't know if the term $2 ^{n}$ is correct, and I don't know its meaning.

Comment: It depends on whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  If they are (you have assumed this but it is not in the original statement of the question) and  you write your final result as $P(X+Y=n)=\dfrac{e^{-2\lambda}(2\lambda)^n}{n!}$ then you have a Poisson distribution with parameter $2\lambda$